# Dao class must be annotated with @Dao - androidx.room.Dao

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I see this error list.

```
1) Dao class must be annotated with @Dao - androidx.room.Dao
2) An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery - java.lang.annotation.Annotation.equals(java.lang.Object)
```

and other like in second point.

Please Help me.

My Dao Class

```
package database
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface UserDao{
    //Product
    @Query("SELECT * FROM product")
     @Delete
    fun deleteProduct(product: Product)

    //Order
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `Order`")
    fun getOrderList():List<Order>
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertOrder(order: Order)
    @Delete
    fun deleteOrder(order: Order)
    ....
}
```

My Entity Class

```
package database

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name") val productName:String?,
)
@Entity
data class Order(
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_id") val clientId:Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date:String?
)
.......
```

My Database Class

```
package database

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(
    entities = [Product::class, Order::class, OrderBody::class,
        OrderToPurchase::class,Price::class,Client::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class AppDatabase:RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun userDao():Dao
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:-

```
abstract fun userDao():UserDao
```

That is the userDao function should be returning a Type of **UserDao** not a Type of Dao.

You would then have an issue with :-

```
//Product
@Query("SELECT * FROM product")
 @Delete
fun deleteProduct(product: Product)
```

This is because the @Query does not have associated function. Instead you want something like:-

```
//Product
@Query("SELECT * FROM product")
fun getProductList(): List<Product> //<<<<< ADDED
@Delete
fun deleteProduct(product: Product)
```